# Read a txt file to grep information over a list of files

Tags: bash

I have 20 files with different types of information for a list of cities.

For all the files, I want to grep the information of a given city, so, if for example I have three cities (NewYork, Barcelona, Rome), I would like to generate three files (NewYork.txt, Barcelona.txt, Rome.txt),
with all the information in the 20 files for those cities.

I can do this easily with the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

list=("NewYork", "Barcelona", "Rome")

for i in "${list[@]}"
do
   echo $i
   zgrep -Hx $i *.vcf.gz > $i.txt
done
echo "Done"
```

However, there are two dificulties:

- First, the list of cities is huge, so I need the script to read a txt file with the list of cities for which I want the data, instead of creating the list manually inside the script.
- Secondly, the files with the information of the cities is in the folder `C:/Users/Roy/DataReceived`, and I want to store the output `.txt` in `C:/Users/Roy/Documents/Results`.

This is script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in C:/Users/Roy/DataReceived/*; do
   while read i; do
      zgrep -Hwi $i *.vcf.gz > $i.txt
   done < list_of_cities.txt
done
```

This script would be stored in `C:/Users/Roy/Documents/Results`, so there's where the files would be created.

However, I'm getting the error 'gzip: *.vcf.gz: No such file or directory'. It's not recognizing the file, so I guess there's something wrong with the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script is wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in C:/Users/Roy/DataReceived/*; do
   while read i; do
      zgrep -Hwi $i *.vcf.gz > $i.txt
   done < list_of_cities.txt
done
```

1. Windows path: `C:/Users` is not valid in bash, and you would have to use `/c/Users`. This may work, but probably not as you intend.
2. You are trying to read all files in `DataReceived` and you don't use the FILE you read.
3. Your `zgrep` is not working as you intend because `*.vcf.gz` is evaluated against the current directory (`$PWD`), and in your example bash find nothing because there is nothing (yup).
4. Your cities may contains space in their name: `New York` and so on, but your don't escape the word itself.

I think you should rewrite your script like this:

```
while read -r city; do
  zgrep -Hwi "$city" *.vcf.gz > "${city}.txt"
done < list_of_cities.txt
```

The quote ensure at least that space in the name does not cause problem, even if there may be problematic characters for filenames (and in Windows, this would be : `/`, `\`, `:`, `?`, `"`, `*`, `<`, `>` and `|`).

The script will look for all `*.vcf.gz` file in the current directory.

[edit] if you need to change input/output directory, you can do so:

```
while read -r city; do
  zgrep -Hwi "$city" "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/"*.vcf.gz > "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${city}.txt"
done < list_of_cities.txt
```

Either your hardcode the path before the `while` read loop:

```
declare INPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/DataReceived
declare OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Results
```

Or if you want to change them before invocation:

```
[[ -z "${INPUT_DIRECTORY}" ]] && INPUT_DIRECTORY="$PWD"
[[ -z "${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" ]] && OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="$PWD"
```

Then you can invoke your script like this:

```
INPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/DataReceived OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Results ./yourscript.bash
```

Or:

```
export INPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/DataReceived
export OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/c/Users/Roy/Documents/Results
./yourscript.bash
```

Comment: Thanks @DataNotFound. So if I look for the files in the currect directory. How can I save them somewhere else? Would something like `> "/c/Users/Roy//Documents/Results/${city}.txt"` work?

Comment: That's fantastic. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm facing an unexpected error with the file labeling. In case you know something about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980658/saved-files-in-aws-using-bash-have-an-unrecognized-name